# Como receber informações do HTML no node js

Tags: html5, node.js

Olá gostaria de saber como eu posso receber os dados do meu formulário no HTML no node js, tenho o formulário de login e quero receber e verificar se este usuário é válido, porém quero que verificar em meu arquivo que verificar isso em meu arquivo conexão.js que vai ser feito em node, e se for válido redirecionar ele pra index, já tô a alguns dias nisso, tentei com:

```
req.body.username
```

Mas não funciona, então gostaria de saber como posso enviar os dados desse formulário para meu arquivo node js para tratar essas informações e retornar ao cliente, quero fazer isso usando Ajax, sei que não é a melhor opção mais acho que é mais fácil pra mim.

Comment: como esta o seu formulario HTML? usou metodo `POST`? voce usa o `express` no seu Node e se sim, voce configurou o `express.urlencoded()`?  Faltou voce mostrar mais do seu codigo, para podermos ajudar no seu problema. Tente editar a sua pergunta.

Comment: Sim, eu consegui com req.body.username, configurei certinho, e usei método post na rota e no HTML, mas não consigo usar isso no arquivo conexão.js, quero usar este arquivo só pra verificar se o usuário existe, não quero ter que criar uma rota para isso.

Comment: e o que aparece no `req.body.username`. Se esta usando AJAX, quer dizer que voce recebe um JSON. configurou o `express.json()`?

Comment: Não usei Ajax, preciso usar ele eu acho, talvez seja melhor, e o que retorna do req.body.username é o nome do usuário que é preenchido no input.

Answer (score 0):

Você  teria que usar o **middleware - body-parser**

Se estiver usando o express ficaria assim.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.post('/login', urlencodedParse, function(req, res){

     var  username = req.body.username
     var  pass     = req.body.password

});
```

Comment: Teria como eu fazer isso sem criar uma rota?